# Is it possible to do standard input AND pass a command line argument in the same line?

Tags: bash

I have a program stored in programfile in which I want to pass command line arguments (with the contents of the file of varargs). I also want to take input on stdin from the contents of file p. I then want to store the final output into variable output.

This is what I have:

```
"$programfile" "${varargs}" < "${p}" > "$output"
```

I'm not sure if this is correct or not as I think my syntax is off somewhere?

Comment: Looks correct. I do "mysql mydb < script.sql > out.log" all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Looks fine to me, as long as you meant that you are storing the final output into a file whose name is in the variable `output`. If you wanted to put the output into a variable you should use backticks or `$()`.

Answer (score 0):

As you have it, your output would go to a file named after the value of `$output`, not the variable itself. You could do something like:

```
output=$("$programfile" "${varargs}" < "${p}")
```

Comment: Hmm so when I do that and try to echo output, it seems to have exited the program completely as it will not echo the output

Comment: What happens when you do `"$programfile" "${varargs}" < "${p}"` by itself?

Answer (score 0):

The redirector `>` is usually used to redirect the output to a file or device. For example,

```
ls > list.txt
```

But to store the result as a variable you will need to do:

```
result=`ls`
```

The usage of `<` is correct.

Comment: Although I prefer dollar parens as above and a [lot of people seem to agree.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated)